# Passing a method from a parent to a child component (without using handlers)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arguments, parent-child

I'm struggling a bit on the following:
- I have 2 components, Album.js and PlayerBar.js
- I have defined a method `formatTime()` in Album.js and would like to pass it to PlayerBar.

Objective: In PlayerBar, I woud like to call the `formatTime()` method to convert time duration from ss to hh.mm.ss. . I know how to pass methods as event handlers but in this case, the method should always apply (it's not based on a click, or mousehover event...). I tried in some way, but I am still not able to pass the method from parent to child, and call it from child to convert the duration.

Album.js (parent component) [(full code)](https://jsfiddle.net/g3y5bwpo/)

```
    class Album extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);

    formatTime(duration) {
        var d = Number(duration);
        var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
        var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

        var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " " : ":") : "";
        var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? ":" : ":") : "";
        var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? ":" : " ") : "";
        return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay;
        }

 //...

 <PlayerBar
         isPlaying={this.state.isPlaying}
         currentSong={this.state.currentSong}
         currentTime={this.audioElement.currentTime}
         duration={this.audioElement.duration}
         formatTime={() => this.formatTime(this.currentTime)}
         volume={this.state.volume}
         handleSongClick={() => this.handleSongClick(this.state.currentSong)}
         handlePrevClick={() => this.handlePrevClick()}
         handleNextClick={() => this.handleNextClick()}
         handleTimeChange={(e) => this.handleTimeChange(e)}
         handleVolumeChange={(e) => this.handleVolumeChange(e)}

         />
```

PlayerBar.js (child component) [(full code)](https://jsfiddle.net/1sr6ej8v/)

```
//...

    <div className="current-time">{this.props.formatTime(this.props.currentTime)}</div>
```

Comment: Which component are your trying to bind `formatTime` to?  It appears to be in Album, but you're calling it using `this` in PlayerBar.

Comment: pass the function ref as `formatTime={this.formatTime}`, and from child call it as `<div className="current-time">{this.props.formatTime(this.props.currentTime)}</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an event handler you can change

`formatTime={() => this.formatTime(this.currentTime)}`

to

`formatTime={this.formatTime}`

Comment: that will not pass the function, it will pass the value returned by the function.

Comment: Yes sorry, answered too fast :)

Answer (score 0):

In Album.js change `formatTime` prop to following

```
formatTime={this.formatTime}
```

or

```
formatTime={(time) => this.formatTime(time)}
```